# When to use IComparable<T> Vs. IComparer<T>

Tags: .net, icomparable, icomparer

I'm trying to figure out which of these interfaces I need to implement. They both essentially do the same thing. When would I use one over the other?

Comment: Great examples and explanation is found here:
https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Well they are not *quite* the same thing as `IComparer<T>` is implemented on a type that is capable of comparing two different objects while `IComparable<T>` is implemented on types that are able to compare themselves with other instances of the same type.

I tend to use `IComparable<T>` for times when I need to know how another instance relates to `this` instance.  `IComparer<T>` is useful for sorting collections as the `IComparer<T>` stands outside of the comparison.

Comment: IComparer<T> also allows you to have a class for each type of sort you want. Example; PersonLastFirstNameComparer, PersonFirstLastNameComparer, or PersonAgeComparer.

Comment: Is there an easy way you use to remember them?  I tend to have to look it up each time.

Comment: @amadib think `IComparable` as _I'm comparable_. which means I can be compared to something else. And read `IComparer` as _I'm a comparer, I simply compare_ which means I compare some things.

Comment: @newfal You should have put this as an answer.  I think it is the best explanation here.

Answer (score 44):

Use `IComparable<T>` when the class has an intrinsic comparison.

Use `IComparer<T>` when you want a comparison method other than the class' intrinsic comparison, if it has one.

Answer (score 30):

It depends on the entity. For example following for a class like "Student", it will make sense to have IComparable based on Name.

```
class Student : IComparable 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MathScore { get; set; }
    public int EnglishScore { get; set; }

    public int TotalScore 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.MathScore + this.EnglishScore; 
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return CompareTo(obj as Student);  
    }

    public int CompareTo(Student other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);  
    }
}
```

But if a teacher 'A' wants to compare students based on MathScore, and teacher 'B' wants to compare students based on EnglishScore. It will be good idea to implement IComparer separately. (More like a strategy pattern)

```
class CompareByMathScore : IComparer<Student>
{
    public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
    {
        if (x.MathScore > y.MathScore)
          return 1;
        if (x.MathScore < y.MathScore)
          return -1;
        else
          return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the Compare method _static_ for easy of use.

Answer (score 14):

**Simple Explanation via a story**

High school basketball. It's a school yard pick for the teams. I want to get the tallest/best/fastest folks on my team. What do I do?

**IComparer Interface** - Compare two people separate people

- This allows me to compare any two guys lined up.........that's basically it. Fred vs John..........i throw them into a concrete class which implements the interface. `Compare(Fred, John)` and it spits out who's better.

**What about IComparable?** - Compare yourself with someone else

Have you been on FB recently? You see other folks doing cool things: travelling the world, creating inventions, while I'm doing something not quite as cool - well what we are doing is making use of the IComparable interface.

- We are comparing the current instance (yourself) with another object (someone else) which is of the same type (person).

**What about the Comparer Class?**

The Comparer class is an abstract base class which implements the IComparer interface. You should derive from this class to have a concrete implementation. anyways, Microsoft recommends that you DO use the Comparer class rather than implement the IComparer interface:

> We recommend that you derive from the Comparer class instead of implementing the IComparer interface, because the Comparer class provides an explicit interface implementation of the IComparer.Compare method and the Default property that gets the default comparer for the object.

#### Summary

- IComparer - line up two things and compare.
- IComparable - compare yourself with others on FB.

Hope the stories help you remember.

Comment: I like your way to illustrating the key concept. It could be better if you including the Comparer(T) class into this contest. Even it's not including in the question. :)

Answer (score 10):

It all depends on whether your type is mutable or not.  You should **only** implement IComparable on non-mutable types.  Note that if you implement IComparable, you must override Equals, along with the ==, !=, < and > operators (see Code Analysis warning CA1036).

Quoting Dave G from [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/12/15/316601.aspx#7537755):

> But the correct answer is to implement IComparer instead of IComparable if your objects are mutable, and pass an instance of the IComparer to sorting functions when necessary.
>
> Since the IComparer is just a disposable object used for sorting at that point in time, your object can have any mutable semantics you desire. Furthermore, it doesn't require or even suggest using Equals, GetHashCode, or == - you're free to define it in any way you please.
>
> Finally, you can define multiple IComparer's for your type for sorting on different fields or with different rules. This is much more flexible than being stuck with one definition.
>
> *In short:* **Use IComparable for value types and IComparer for reference types.**

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, they don't do the same thing.

In any case, these days I tend not to use IComparer. Why would I? Its responsibility (an external entity used to compare two objects) can be handled much cleaner with a lambda expression, similar to how most of LINQ's methods work. Write a quick lambda which takes the objects to compare as arguments, and returns a bool. And if the object defines its own intrinsic compare operation, it can implement IComparable instead.

Comment: -1: returning a bool is not equivalent to IComparer.  IComparer returns a value that can be less than zero/zero/greater than zero and is typically used for sorting.

Comment: And when that is what you need, you return an int (or better still, an enum) instead. Is that really a big deal?

Comment: You can even return a bool, since less than is the only operation you need in order to sort a sequence.

Comment: an IComparer implementation only needs to be defined once, if you need to use the sorting logic in more places, then the lambda expression will need to be written more times.

Comment: oɔɯǝɹ - Then you can store a reference to the delegate that was written as a lambda expression are reuse it as well.

Answer (score 4):

IComparer is a interface which is used to sort the Array, this interface will force the class to implement the 
Compare(T x,T y) method, which will compare the two objects. The instance of the class which implemented this interface is used in the sorting of the Array.

IComparable is a interface is implemented in the type which needs to compare the two objects of the same type, This comparable interface will force the class to implement the following method  CompareTo(T obj)

IEqualityComparer is a interface which is used to find the object whether it is Equal or not, Now we will see this in a sample where we have to find the Distinct of a Object in a collection. This interface will implement a method 
Equals(T obj1,T obj2)

Now we take a Example we have a Employee class , based on this class we have to create a Collection. Now we have the following requirements.

Sort the Array using Array class
2. Need an collection using Linq : Remove the Duplicate, Order by higher to lower, Remove one employee id

```
abstract public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { set; get; }
}

public enum SortType
{
    ByID,
    BySalary
}
```

public class EmployeeIdSorter : IComparer
        {
            public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
            {
                if (x.Id < y.Id)
                    return 1;
                else if (x.Id > y.Id)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }

```
    public class EmployeeSalarySorter : IComparer<Employee>
    {
        public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            if (x.Salary < y.Salary)
                return 1;
            else if (x.Salary > y.Salary)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

For more info refere below 
http://dotnetvisio.blogspot.in/2015/12/usage-of-icomparer-icomparable-and.html

Answer (score 3):

IComparable says an object can be compared with another.
IComparer is an object that can compare any two items.