# What there is two Interface(Icomparable,Icomparer) for comparison?

Tags: .net, collections, icomparable, icomparer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use IComparable<T> Vs. IComparer<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538096/when-to-use-icomparablet-vs-icomparert)

while IComparer works for both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests `IComparable` is thing that can be compared and `IComparar` is an object that can compare other objects. If you want to compare two objects of same type then you will implement `IComparable` on it. If you want a type that can compare other objects then you will implement `IComparer`.