# Operator overloading?

Tags: c#, operators

I've made myself a rss reader that keeps me up to date and informs me on new shows, or atleast thats the thought behind.

I've made a struct "SeasonEpisode" that hold two ints (season+episode) and a override ToString function.

I store the latest watched locally and i then read whats the newest is from the rss. But how could I compare SeasonEpisodes? right now I take each of the ints and compare them

```
if( se1.Season >= se2.Season )
    if( se1.Episode > se2.Episode || se1.Season > se2.Season )
        // new episode!
```

What i really want is

```
if( se1 > se2 )
    // new episode
```

Could i get any help please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Implement [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) and use `CompareTo`
2. [Overload the greater and less than operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I suggest, you use both ways:

```
public class SeasonEpisode : IComparable<SeasonEpisode>
{
    public int CompareTo(SeasonEpisode other)
    {
        if(other == null)
            return 1;
        if(Season == other.Season)
        {
            if(Episode == other.Episode)
                return 0;
            else if(Episode < other.Episode)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        else if(Season < other.Season) 
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    public static bool operator <(SeasonEpisode e1, SeasonEpisode e2) 
    {
        return e1.CompareTo(e2) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(SeasonEpisode e1, SeasonEpisode e2) 
    {
        return e1.CompareTo(e2) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The operators will throw a `NullReferenceException` in case `e1` is `null`.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit That's correct. Thanks for [your correction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32481449/572644).

Answer (score 3):

As i tripped over a `NullReferenceException`, here's an improvement (well this may be subjective ;-)) to [Daniel Hilgarth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5672992/684096).

The only change is that it handles `null`s in case the first argument to the `>` or `<` operator is null:

```
public class SeasonEpisode : IComparable<SeasonEpisode>
{
    private static int Compare(SeasonEpisode e1, SeasonEpisode e2)
    {
        if (e1 == null && e2 == null)
            return 0;
        else if (e1 == null)
            return -1;
        else if (e2 == null)
            return 1;

        if(e1.Season == e2.Season)
        {
            if(e1.Episode == e2.Episode)
                return 0;
            else if(e1.Episode < e2.Episode)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        else if(e1.Season < e2.Season) 
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }    

    public int CompareTo(SeasonEpisode other)
    {
        return Compare(this, other);
    }

    public static bool operator <(SeasonEpisode e1, SeasonEpisode e2) 
    {
        return Compare(e1, e2) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(SeasonEpisode e1, SeasonEpisode e2) 
    {
        return Compare(e1, e2) > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) interface

> Defines a method that a type implements to compare two objects.

You can implement `IComparable` if you want *a class to be comparable* to another instance of that class. Which is probably what you want, in this case.

Implement `IComparer` if you need *a class that compares two objects*.

Comment: (Worded for the old version of your answer, the edit of your answer didn't change the notion of my comment, though. Too lazy to re-word...) That's not really the correct interface to use here. You would either need a comparer class that implements this interface or implement it in `SeasonEpisode` and call it like this: `se1.Compare(se1, se2)`. A bit ackward. `IComparable<T>` is what you want to use here. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538096/when-to-use-icomparablet-vs-icomparert