# Cannot apply operator '>=' to operator of type X and 'float'

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean-operations

I am new to stackoverflow and here to learn.

How can one apply the operator '>=' to an If statement in C# when they are not of the same data type?

```
MyClass usingMyClass = ...; // (instance variable)

if (usingMyClass.MyClass >= price) // price is a float
```

Any solutions?

Comment: [c# reference: operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: What does >= mean in this case? How is your class comparable to a float? It's not clear what you're trying to solve, so it is hard to offer a solution.

Comment: You *could* define comparison operators on `MyClass` but the real issue here is why it even makes sense to do this comparison in the first place. Without knowing more, I'd say you probably need to use a `Price` property to do the comparison so that you know you're comparing semantically similar things: `if (usingMyClass.MyClass.Price >= price)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672973/operator-overloading)

Comment: While you're at it, don't use `float` or `double` for prices. [Use `decimal`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270490/printing-components-from-a-list-of-objects-dont-work#comment97272182_55270490)

Comment: Please show us the code for the type MyClass

Comment: You must intend that comparison to *mean* something, so let's dig into that. Under *exactly* what circumstances should that expression result in `true`?

Comment: The MyClass should operate as a DebitCard class. 

So basically:

`public class DebitCard
{
 public float Balance{ get; set; }

 public DebitCard()
 {
  Balance = new Random().Next();
 }

So basically:

 if(customer.DebitCard >= product.GetPrice(){
   performTransaction();
  }`

Comment: Any idea how to add linebreak in code? <br/> dont seem to work.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the requested information instead of leaving it in comments.

Comment: Meanwhile, I will paraphrase my earlier comment: The card itself isn't an amount of money. It can have several properties, including the balance. You need to compare the card's balance to the price.

Comment: Right, I don't understand why you are trying to compare the card to the price. If the intention is to compare the balance to the price then compare the balance to the price.  Also it is worthwhile noting that (1) madreflection is correct; **never use float for money**, and (2) though modeling bank accounts is a common beginner exercise, real bank account software is nothing like a mutable class that has a balance. Real bank account software is an append-only ledger of all transactions that took place in the account, from which the balance is computed.

Comment: @EricLippert: to be fair, I linked to *your* comment to make that point.

Comment: @madreflection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv7jcciKB_s

Comment: @EricLippert: I'm not sure how to take that. Nevertheless, I found it entertaining.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution to your specific problem -- how do I compare a bank account balance to a price? -- is NOT to compare the bank account to the price. The correct solution is to make a property `Balance` on the account object and compare *that* to the price.

---

ASIDE: "Bank account" is a common beginner exercise, and I wish it was not, because it gives a completely wrong idea of how bank account software actually works. In real-world bank account software, the logic that determines whether there is sufficient balance to back a particular purchase happens in multiple phases. The proposed workflow -- determine if the account has sufficient funds, and if so, perform the transaction -- is flawed because what can happen is there can be *two* transactions in flight, there is enough cash to cover both individually but not both together, both checks succeed, both transactions happen, and the account ends up overdrawn.  Designing a realistic system that is high performance and avoids this problem is difficult, and not a beginner exercise.

Moreover, as I mentioned in a comment, real bank account software never has a "mutable balance". Rather, it is a write-only-at-the-end ledger of all transactions since the start of the account, from which the balance can be computed. You never want anything *mutable* in a bank account because it is then too easy to commit frauds.

Also, as noted in the comments, **never use float or double to represent money**. Use `decimal`. It was designed for that task. Use floats and doubles for *physical quantities* like length or mass or speed.

---

To answer your actual question: to make a class that implements its own user-defined comparison operators you can use *operator overloading*. However, you should note that **it is very easy to get it wrong, particularly for comparison operators**.  My advice for beginners and experts alike when implementing comparison logic is to implement *one method* that does *all* comparisons and then *call* that method from *every* overloaded operator. I give an example of how to do this correctly here:

https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/

Notice that there is a *lot* of work to do. You need to overload `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `Equals`, and `GetHashCode` to do this correctly.