# Support multiple comparison-types for IEquatable

Tags: vb.net

I overloaded Equals method which looks like that right now:

```
 Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Part) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of Part).Equals
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Return (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
    End Function
```

As you see i am comparing according to PartName and PartId. And use it like below:

```
 Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Contains(""1734""): {0}", parts.Contains(New Part() With { _
            .PartId = 1334, _
            .PartName = "chain rin8g" _
       }))
```

Apart from that i would like to be able also to compare only PartId or partName separetly. So what i did was to create Enum:

```
Public Enum EqualsComparmission

    PartId
    PartName
    PartId_and_PartName

End Enum
```

So what i did was to add additional method:

```
  Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Part, compParameter As EqualsComparmission) As Boolean


        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim result As Boolean

        Select Case compParameter
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                result = (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId))
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                result = (Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                result = (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
            Case Else

        End Select

        Return result
    End Function
```

But after that i am not able to use e.g:

```
Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Contains(""1734""): {0}",
parts.Contains(New Part() With { _
.PartId = 1334, _
.PartName = "chain rin8g" _
}), EqualsComparmission.PartId)
```

the entire Part class:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
' Simple business object. A PartId is used to identify the type of part  
' but the part name can change.  
Public Class Part
    Implements IEquatable(Of Part)
    Public Property PartName() As String
        Get
            Return m_PartName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_PartName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_PartName As String

    Public Property PartId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_PartId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_PartId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_PartId As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "ID: " & PartId & "   Name: " & PartName
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        Dim objAsPart As Part = TryCast(obj, Part)
        If objAsPart Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Equals(objAsPart)
        End If
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return PartId
    End Function
    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Part) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of Part).Equals
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Return (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Part, compParameter As EqualsComparmission) As Boolean
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim result As Boolean

        Select Case compParameter
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                result = (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId))
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                result = (Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                result = (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
            Case Else

        End Select
        Return result
    End Function


    ' Should also override == and != operators. 

End Class
```

**EDIT For further discussion:**

I wanted to test something because if 'Remove' method is referring to Equals method of IEqutable (according to MSDN) i implements Equtable again and modified Equals method to be prepared for Remove correctly. Unfortunetly somehow when i am calling remove like this below it always going to EqualsComparmission.PartId of case no matter what i define - this case : **EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName**

its going to this part of Equal method:

```
Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId)
```

this is how i use it:

```
   Dim deleted As Boolean = parts.Remove(New Part(EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) With { _
             .PartId = 11, _
             .PartName = "al7a" _
        })

        Console.WriteLine("Found and deleted: true/false: : " & deleted )
```

entire class:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Part
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Part), IEquatable(Of Part)


    Public Property ComparisonType As EqualsComparmission

    Public Sub New(comparisonType As EqualsComparmission)
        Me.ComparisonType = comparisonType
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property PartName() As String
        Get
            Return m_PartName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_PartName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_PartName As String

    Public Property PartId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_PartId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_PartId = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_PartId As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "ID: " & PartId & "   Name: " & PartName
    End Function


    Public Function Equals1(x As Part, y As Part) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).Equals
        If x Is Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return True
        If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return False

        Select Case ComparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId AndAlso String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & ComparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As Part) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).GetHashCode
        Select Case ComparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return obj.PartId
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return If(obj.PartName Is Nothing, 0, obj.PartName.GetHashCode())
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Dim hash = 17

                hash = hash * 23 + obj.PartId
                hash = hash * 23 + If(obj.PartName Is Nothing, 0, obj.PartName.GetHashCode())
                Return hash
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & ComparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Part) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Part).Equals
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Select Case ComparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Return (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & ComparisonType.ToString())
        End Select

        Return (Me.PartId.Equals(other.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(other.PartName))
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I would create a custom `IEqualityComparer(Of Part)` which has that enum as property and also as constructor parameter. Then you can use it for most LINQ methods like [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: what do you mean can you give some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a custom `IEqualityComparer(Of Part)` which has that enum as property and also as constructor parameter. Then you can use it for most LINQ methods like [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.100).aspx).

What I have in mind is:

```
Public Class PartComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Part)

    Public Sub New(comparisonType As EqualsComparison)
        Me.ComparisonType = comparisonType
    End Sub

    Public Property ComparisonType As EqualsComparison = EqualsComparison.PartId

    Public Function Equals1(x As Part, y As Part) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).Equals
        If x Is Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return True
        If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return False

        Select Case ComparisonType
            Case EqualsComparison.PartId
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId
            Case EqualsComparison.PartName
                Return String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparison.PartId_and_PartName
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId AndAlso String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & ComparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As Part) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).GetHashCode
        Select Case ComparisonType
            Case EqualsComparison.PartId
                Return obj.PartId
            Case EqualsComparison.PartName
                Return If(obj.PartName Is Nothing, 0, obj.PartName.GetHashCode())
            Case EqualsComparison.PartId_and_PartName
                Dim hash = 17

                hash = hash * 23 + obj.PartId
                hash = hash * 23 + If(obj.PartName Is Nothing, 0, obj.PartName.GetHashCode())
                Return hash
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & ComparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

You  use it in this way(with `Enumerable.Contains`, but can be used also with other LINQ methods):

```
Dim contains As Boolean = parts.Contains(New Part() With { _
        .PartId = 1334, _
        .PartName = "chain rin8g" _
   }, New PartComparer(EqualsComparison.PartId_and_PartName))
```

---

According to your comments you want to remove one (or multiple) parts of a `List(Of Part)` by providing a given `Part` and a `EqualsComparison`. You could write an extension like:

```
Module Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Remove(partList As List(Of Part), partToDelete As Part, comparisonType As EqualsComparison, Optional onlyOne As Boolean = True)
        Dim comparer = New PartComparer(comparisonType)
        For i As Int32 = partList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If comparer.Equals(partList(i), partToDelete) Then
                partList.RemoveAt(i)
                If onlyOne Then Return
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now this works:

```
Dim partToDelete = New Part With {.PartId = 4711}
parts.Remove(partToDelete, EqualsComparison.PartId)
```

Comment: i will check that, can you tell me why you add parameter to IEqualityComparer(Of Part) and not just to add to IEquatable(Of Part) ? Whats the diffrence

Comment: You could also implement `IEquatable(Of Part)` in the same way. If you want to know the difference and what to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316918/what-is-the-difference-between-iequalitycomparert-and-iequatablet. I use mostly `IEqualityComparer(Of T)` because it allows to provide different implementations and it dows not need to modify the original class. But in this case the comparer itself supports different implementations implicitly.

Comment: i see and it works, the only one issue i have right now is remove method not working correctly :  Dim czyByloIUsunieto As Boolean = parts.Remove(New Part() With { _
             .PartId = 1434, _
             .PartName = "regular seat" _
        })

Comment: @unknown: so what do you want to remove, every part with that ID or with that name, or with both, or only the first found? Either override `Equals` or use `List.RemoveAll` with f.e.: `parts.RemoveAll(Function(p) p.PartId = 1434)`

Comment: when use remove when was using IEquatable the it was working and refering to equal method. So in your code it should works as well right refering to Equals1 (btw why Equals1 not Equals?)?

Comment: @unknown: you can name it as you like in VB.NET because of the `Implements ...` statement. But if it's named `Equals` it hides([Shadows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6.aspx)) the `Equals` from object which this class also inherits. You don't want to compare `PartComparer`s but `Part`s. According to my last comment, if you just want to delete one part from the list (and there could be multiple with a given ID) you could also use `Dim index=parts.FindIndex(Function(p) p.PartId = 1434) parts.RemoveAt(index)`

Comment: its strange when i used IEqutable interface according to msdna: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 they claiming Remove method is refering to Equal method but it in your example looks like its just list function. Can you explain?

Comment: @unknown: `List.Remove` uses `Equals` to determine if two objects are equal. Otherwise `List.Remove` does not find the given object that you want to remove. I can show you an example how you could extend `List(Of Part)` to provide a method that supports a `EqualsComparison`.... **Done**

Comment: can you look at my first post i putted there Edit clause, can you explain me why its happening to me?

Comment: @unknown: a question on SO is not supposed to be an endless discussion, you might want to ask a different question which addresses that issue. Otherwise this question will not be very helpful for future readers.

Comment: i make another topic would you be so kind take a look on it?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842628/equals-remove-wrong-assigment-inside-equals