# IEquatable<T> with GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, equality, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

I have created a Graph Class including `HashSet<T>` as Nodes and `HashSet<IEdge<T>>` as Edges.

```
public interface IEdge<T>
{
    T A_Node { get; }
    T Another_Node { get; }
}


public interface IGraph<T>
{
    ISet<T> Nodes { get; }
    ISet<IEdge<T>> Edges { get; }
}
```

I want to avoid adding duplicate Nodes and Edges to my Graph.

Based on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316918/what-is-the-difference-between-iequalitycomparert-and-iequatablet) :

> **1)** *IEqualityComparer* is an interface for an object that performs the
>   comparison on two objects of the type T.
>
> **2)** *IEquatable* is for an object of type T so that it can compare itself
>   to another.

also

> **3)** If there is only one way of testing two instances of T for equality,
>   or if one of several methods is preferred One instance of T has
>   internal knowledge of how to compare itself to another instance of T.
>
> **4)** On the other hand, if there are several equally reasonable methods of
>   comparing two Ts for equality, IEqualityComparer would seem more
>   appropriate
>
> **5)** This interface is not meant to be implemented by T itself, but by
>   other "external" classes.

Based on these tips(1-5) and my code, I need to have IEdge be able to compare itself to another.

Also there is only one way of testing two instances of T or IEdge for equality.

So It seems Implementing IEquatable is the solution.

But the **problem** is that HashSets use **GetHashCode** method.

And IEquatable doesn't force to override GetHashCode method.

How can I use IEquatable and in the same time force the developer to override GetHashCode ?!

If you prefer using `IEqualityComparer<T>` or `EqualityComparer<T>` in this case, doesn't it matter that it has conflict with Tips above ?

Comment: You could encapsulate the collection of edges and in a provided `Add()` method, perform the duplication checks you want. It would be up to the concrete `Graph` type then to deal with that, which seems like it makes sense anyway.

Comment: But I think if the T or IEdge<T> has an overrided GetHashCode method , the HashSet works better. And I'm searching for a way to force developer to override GetHashCode too by using Interfaces. There is EqualityComparer but I think it's concept does not match.Is using EqualityComparer wrong or it's ok !?

Comment: No, `IEqualityComparer<IEdge>` is for something else comparing edges. Like if you wanted to allow someone to specify a custom equality check for my proposed `Add()` method, you could have an `IEqualityComparer<IEdge> comparer` parameter. Then the `Add()` method would do something like `comparer.Equals(edge1, edge2)`.

Comment: Are you talking about having `IEdge<T>` implement `IEqualityComparer<IEdge<T>>`? Because even if you do that, `HashSet<T>` won't use the `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T)` implementation by default. If you don't provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to `HashSet<T>` then it just uses the default one which uses `object.GetHashCode` and either `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` or `object.Equals(object)`.

Comment: Yeah, I reckon you'll be wanting to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` to use with the HashSet, and pass it to the appropriate HashSet constructor.

Comment: Types that implement `IEquatable<T>` should already override `GetHashCode` (and `Equals(object)`) - see the [remarks in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-implementers).

Comment: @Lee I find it weird based on the links you sent that when we implement IEquatable<T> we should also override GetHashCode method BUT this isn't forced in IEquatable interface ! I think finally I should remind and ask the one who use my library to override GetHashCode too ! Kinda Odd !

Comment: Interfaces can't require implementers to override other virtual methods and since `GetHashCode` is defined in `object` there isn't a way to enforce it in the type system. Ideally `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode` wouldn't be defined on `object` at all.

Comment: As @Lee has explained, an interface simply states what members a type must implement. Since all types in .NET already implement `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`, all objects trivially would satisfy any such requirement in an interface. If you want to enforce implementation, you need to use an `abstract` class instead (which in a very real sense is just an interface that optionally has some implementation already defined). See marked duplicate.