# Difference between .Equals, IComparable and IComparer

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone please explain with example that I can understand about the difference between .Equals, IComparable and IComparer.

I was asked this in an interview.

Comment: `Equals` returns true/false if the two objects are equal (or the same reference depending on your implementation) IComparable/IComparer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980780/difference-between-icomparable-and-icomparer

Comment: Please search it on the internet you will get lots of resource answering your query here is one from me (I mean MS) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727

Comment: oh my! such an easy question for interview.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but he was asking does Equals compare both strings and integers or he put this way, like reference type and value type.... He confused me :(

Comment: Dharnitski, HatSoft, thank you but really not the link I am expecting here. Also Dharnitski, MSDN I cant understand most thing (Like many small developers like me does)... Any document/tutorial is considered as good ONLY if it is reachable to even small minds :) Appreciate you folks though....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well first off, on the surface, `Equals` is a method (present in every object), while `IComparable` and `IComparer` are interfaces.

`Equals` is present in any class and can be overriden to provide equality testing depending on the context of the class (it's a good practice to override `GetHashCode` as well). By default it just tests if objects are equal in memory which is not very useful. `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) are usually given a different implementation in the context of searching or hashing.

Implementing `IComparable` is a more fine-grain way of comparison, as it provides the `CompareTo` method, which is a greater-than/less-than comparison as opposed to `Equals` which is simply a is-equal-or-not comparison. For example a binary search tree structure could benefit from this method.

`IComparer` is similar to `IComparable`, except that it works from the outside. It allows you to define a "neutral" object that is used for comparing two other objects without modifying them directly, which you need to do with `IComparable`.

Comment: Uhmm Nice explanation, I wish I could have seen a small code to understand IComparable. Thank you, good explanation Tudor.

Comment: @Divine: You can find a code snipped at the end of the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

Comment: Thank you Tudor, it helps me a lot :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`Equals` is a method, when 2 other are interfaces. So look like the biggest difference.

More seriously - @ChrisSinclair gave you an answer in comments...

Equals returns true/false if the two objects are equal (or the same reference depending on your implementation) IComparable/IComparer: [difference between IComparable and IComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980780/difference-between-icomparable-and-icomparer)

Answer (score 0):

.Equals() gives your class a way to test for equality against all other possible objects.  This can be considered as the fallback for object equality.  So this answers the question am I equivalent to the object passed in as a param.

IComparable provides for a way of comparing objects which can be ordered, possible uses include sorting.  Implementing this interface puts the ordering logic into your class.

IComparer does pretty much the same as IComparable except the logic is contained in separate class.

Comment: THank you Slugart. Ok if IComparable does the same as IComparer, any good reason to see this in seperate class ?

Comment: Not coupling your comparison code to the class being compared allows you to provide multiple implementations of the ordering logic.  Basic example is a ReverseComparer.

Comment: Thank you Slugart, it helped me understand :) Cheers