# IComparable required to sort column

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid, icomparable

One of the columns in my DevExpress xtragrid is not sorting, grouping or filtering. Answers to similar questions suggest I need to implement IComparable, but when I did that it no longer displays in the column at all.

```
public class Flow : System.IComparable<Flow>
{
  public Flow(int id, string name, string description)
  {
    this.ID = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Description = description;
  }

  public int ID { get; private set; }

  public string Name { get; private set; }

  public string Description { get; private set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    Flow flow = obj as Flow;
    if (flow == null) return false;
    return this.ID == flow.ID;
  }

  public static bool operator ==(Flow flow1, Flow flow2)
  {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, flow1))
      return object.ReferenceEquals(null, flow2);
    return flow1.Equals(flow2);
  }

  public static bool operator !=(Flow flow1, Flow flow2)
  {
    return !(flow1 == flow2);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return ID;
  }

  public int CompareTo(Flow other)
  {
    return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
  }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Asked on [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q470102)...

Comment: To sort I believe you would need IComparer and not IComparable. Check SO answer for details :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538096/when-to-use-icomparablet-vs-icomparert. IComparable would just tell you equals or not but an implementation of IComparer would tell you greater than, equals and less than, thereby allowing you to sort.

Comment: @ryadavilli: It should be `IComparable` as it in an intrinsic comparison.

Comment: @davenewza I am not sure about the datagrid, but in general to sort you would need to know greater or less or equals. A simple CompareTo which just tells equals or not equals, would not help to sort the data. Can you guide me to some documentation to help me understand this?

Comment: It's best to post this question on the DevExpress forums.  `XtraGrid` is such a terribly designed control.  There are probably various properties that you need to set too.

Comment: @ryadavilli:  [IComparable on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).  `IComparable` definitely does indicate greater than, equals or less than.  It is the defacto interface used for object comparison.

Comment: @davenewza Ahhh yes it Does. Thanks for pointing it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disappearing content was an unrelated issue - a red herring. The column allowed sorting once I had implemented `IComparable` rather than `IComparable<Flow>`

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
  if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
    return 1;
  Flow flow = obj as Flow;
  if (flow == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Object is not of type Flow");
  return this.Name.CompareTo(flow.Name);
}
```

Sourced from MSDN documentation for [`IComparable.CompareTo` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CompareTo Method is wrong. Try adding the following to the CompareTo() Method and see if it's working:

```
    public int CompareTo(Flow other)
    {
      // Alphabetic sort if name is equal.
      if this.Name == other.Name
      {
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
      }
     //Default sort.
     return other.Name.CompareTo(this.Name);
    }
```

Let me know if it sorted out your problem.

Comment: Thanks Johan, but this does not change the behaviour of the column.

Comment: Pleasure Michael, I just want to find out, are you adding your values to a List maybe? If not maybe try to create a List of Flow objects eg: List<Flow> list = new List<Flow>(); and after adding all the objects to the list try to use list.Sort(); to try and sort your list and then try to populate your grid with the data

Comment: I was trying to use the built-in devexpress xtragrid functionality. It's working now; see my answer.