# Difference between IComparable and IComparable<K>

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and because of this I found an annoying problem which stop me from making my homework. What's the difference between `IComparable` and `IComparable<K>`?

One of my friend used something like this `Vector_d<T> where T:IComparable`, but everywhere else in source files he used `T:IComparable<T>`. When I asked him, he didn't know to answer so I have to search somewhere else.

Comment: What was the annoying Problem?

Comment: I don't know the exact difference between this two. So I need a hint to know how to use it

Comment: The second one specifies the type being compared

Comment: What have you not understood in the documentation of both interfaces? The   latter is generic.

Comment: The one that uses Type is much safer to use. The reason is because without knowing the Type, you have to cast an Object into a class before comparing, which may cause an error. Whereas knowing the Type in advance, you can compare directly.

Comment: I made some edits that may be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use IComparable<T> Vs. IComparer<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538096/when-to-use-icomparablet-vs-icomparert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one, IComparable, is from the old .NET days, where there were no generics. It basically allows you to compare any type implementing it to any other type, but possibly it will throw an exception, if the types are not comparable.
The generic version, IComparable<>, will only let you compare two values of the same type (or of a derived type), most likely what you want.
Old types, such as Int32, used to implement only IComparable, but now they implement both, but IComparable privately, so as not to be called instead of the generic version.