# Make List<Student> Distinctable with IEquatable<Student>

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

I wanted to make my Class Sortable(By Age) when it stored in List.

I read this : [IComparable Vs IComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538096/when-to-use-icomparablet-vs-icomparert) and I maked my class Sortable .

```
public class Student : IComparable<Student>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Student other)
    {
        if (this.Age > other.Age)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (this.Age < other.Age)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

> List students = new List();
>
> // And Filling students
>
> students.Sort();

Now , I want to make my class Distinctable , I mean when I call .Distinct() it remove duplicate students By ID .

I read [IEquatable VS IEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316918/what-is-the-difference-between-iequalitycomparert-and-iequatablet)
And same as Sort ( That give no argumants ) I expect to call .Distinct() with no passing argumants.

```
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Student other)
        {
            if (this.ID == other.ID)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

> List students = new List();
>
> // And Filling students
>
> students.Distinct();

But when I use this nothing happened .
**WHY ?**

And How can I implement IEquatable and use Distinct() with no passing argumants ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See what `Enumerable.Distinct`'s [docs says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of
>   the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface. To
>   compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and
>   provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

I don't see that your `Student` class:

- ...overrides `Object.GetHashCode(...)`.
- ...overrides `Object.Equals(...)`

In the other hand, `Enumerable.Distinct` returns:

> ...an unordered sequence that contains no duplicate values. It uses the
>   default equality comparer, Default, to compare values.

Thus, you need to set the result to a variable:

```
var x = enumerable.Distinct();
```

### Consider using a `HashSet<T>`

Perhaps you want your collection to contain *unique elements*. If this is the case, don't store elements in a regular collection to later call `Enumerable.Distinct()`, but use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) directly.

Once you've fixed your `Student` class overriding the whole methods mentioned above, you'll be able to store students as follows:

```
HashSet<Student> studentSet = new HashSet<Student();
studentSet.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Name = "Matías", Age = 32 });

// HashSet<T>.Add returns true if it could add the whole element. 
// In our case, this if statement will never enter!
if(studentSet.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Name = "Matías", Age = 32 }))
{
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain : why should we use " var x = students.Distinct(); " ??? It dose not work when I use  " students.Distinct(); " ...

Comment: @Parsa Well not always you need a `HashSet<T>` but at certain point in your application flow you need to get unique elements within a collection so you call `Distinct()`. But if you've identified that you need to **store** unique elements, `HashSet<T>` is the winner!

Comment: @Parsa About `Distinct()`, did you assign the result of calling `Distinct()` to some variable?

Comment: No I did not assign in variable , but as you said , I should do . I was thinking why I shoud ?! , AND I am thinking which one should I choose ? HashSet VS Distinct :)))

Comment: @Parsa Others and me have already said that `Distinct()` doesn't modify the list but it returns a new enumerable containing the whole unique elements.

Comment: @Parsa The decision about using `HashSet<T>` or not is based on checking if you need to store unique elements or you need to be able to repeat items in the same collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136095/discussion-between-parsa-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Answer (score 3):

Distinct like all other LINQ methods return vale rather than modifying original collection.

Fix - asign result to variable or ToList and assign back to students.

Answer (score 0):

You should Implement **IEquable** interface and override **Equals** and **GetHashCode** methods.

Comment: This answer really doesn't add anything to the discussion--it merely restates the first part of Matías Fidemraizer's answer that he gave the day before, albeit in a shorter and easier form.  This may be better suited as a comment to Matías' answer rather than creating a new one.